# org.apache.james.modules.protocols.DefaultImapPackage class source code

Tags: imap, james, apache-james

From where we can get source code of class "org.apache.james.modules.protocols.DefaultImapPackage" used in Apache James server?

Answer (score 1):

They have a github with the code:

https://github.com/apache/james-project

A search there leads to the source file in this directory:

https://github.com/apache/james-project/tree/master/server/container/guice/protocols/imap/src/main/java/org/apache/james/modules/protocols